# Oracle Trigger on Table containing CLOB: ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, triggers, clob

Hi I get the title error whenever I try to SELECT - Not update/insert or make any change - to the triggered table.  I get the trigger to work if I don't select the COB column but as soon as I either try to use substr/instr or xmltype/extract to get at the contents I get the error.

```
SQL> SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE;

VERSION
-----------------
11.2.0.3.0

SQL> desc alert;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ALERTID                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 JOBSTREAMRUNID                                     VARCHAR2(32)
 SEVERITY                                           VARCHAR2(32)
 STATUS                                             NUMBER(38)
 CREATIONTIME                                       FLOAT(126)
 DATAVALUES                                         CLOB
 ALERTTYPE                                          VARCHAR2(255)
```

The trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NEW_ALERT after insert on aedbadmin.alert for each row when severity='critical'
 DECLARE

 BEGIN

  insert into jawstemp (job_name,instance) 
  select xmltype(datavalues).extract('//TARGET_JOB_NAME/text()').getStringVal(),
  xmltype(datavalues).extract('//AUTOSYS_INSTANCE/text()').getStringVal() 
  from alert;
 END;
/
```

sqlldr output:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "ALERT".
ORA-04091: table AEDBADMIN.ALERT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "AEDBADMIN.NEW_ALERT", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'AEDBADMIN.NEW_ALERT'
```

I've also tried splitting the insert into a procedure but it just moves the problem:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "ALERT".
ORA-04091: table AEDBADMIN.ALERT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "AEDBADMIN.NEW_ALERT_PROC", line 6
ORA-06512: at "AEDBADMIN.NEW_ALERT", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'AEDBADMIN.NEW_ALERT'
```

Don't know what else to try..

Please help!

Comment: Do you really mean to use an INSERT trigger FOR EACH ROW which queries all records and attempts to insert into another table? If not for the mutating table error, you'd insert all records every time you insert a row. That hardly seems correct.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually the insert into the jawstemp table was a placeholder.  When working it execs a sp on a remote machine.  Besides, the two xml fields I take are a small part of the whole.

Answer (score 0):

trigger code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NEW_ALERT 
      after insert on aedbadmin.alert 
      for each row 
      when severity='critical'
    DECLARE

    BEGIN

      INSERT INTO jawstemp (job_name,instance) 
      VALUES (
             xmltype(:NEW.datavalues).extract('//TARGET_JOB_NAME/text()').getStringVal(),
             xmltype(:NEW.datavalues).extract('//AUTOSYS_INSTANCE/text()').getStringVal() 
      );
    END;
    /
```

Comment: Thanks MathCurious.  I did try that and it still gets the same error.  It turns out there was nothing wrong with my trigger the problem was my testing method; sqlldr.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was due to me using sql loader to populate table and CLOB.  I guess it takes too long for the CLOB to be populated and even putting a sleep in the trigger didn't work.  The trigger works if I insert text into the clob column without using sqlldr.

I'm hoping the live feeding system doesn't use sqlldr either.